# Corny kegs: Is there a difference between the in coupler and the out coupler?

Tags: kegging, corny-keg, kegs

I have black and grey couplers, one says "in" and the other says "out", but they look exactly the same to me... Does it matter if I use them indiscriminately for gas in/beer out lines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are slightly differently sized. In particular, the grey gas fitting *will* fit over the "out" post, but the black liquid fitting *will not* fit over the "in" post without significant pain.

But, yes you should treat them as the separate things they are.